# How to open Jquery Modal Dialog Box on ImageButton Click

Tags: jquery

I am using vb.net code and I have below code in my application

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlArchive" DefaultButton="ibtnArchive" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Please Enter Your Password to Set Archive:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtArchive" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnArchive" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images1/OK_button.png" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Now I want to open jquery Modal Dialog Box when user clicks above Image Button, Modal Dialog box will be having **Yes** and **No** option. With **my Customize message** on it. Which will **return some values** when **Yes** is clicked or **No** is clicked by user of Modal Dailog Box, so that we can further perform some other code.

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Manoj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#ibtnArchive").click ( function () 
{
   // code for opening your dialog box
});
```

***Edit:***

If you need a simple modal box then please take a look at

[Basic Modal Dialog](http://www.ericmmartin.com/simplemodal/)

Comment: many thanks for your reply, can I have the complete code for opening the jquery modal box according to the above requirement. Please see my question above

Comment: I don't have any code and URL for modal dialog box, can you please clear it more. I have cleary mentioned my requirement in above question

Comment: Hi Dear, I want one more functionality before it calls my jquery dailog box. As you can see it is asking for password, so I need to check password valid condition and if the entered password is valid then it will show my modal dialog box. And when user clicks "Yes" in modal dialog box it should perform .net function.